# Count number of values under specific JSON key

Tags: apex, json, string

I have one JSON output which is parsed from String using JSONParser. Is there a way to check if key "dates" exists and number of values under "dates" in Apex?

```
dates": [
    {
        "surname": "Deer",
        "qualifier": "472",
        "place": "US"
    }, --> This should be 1st item
    {
        "name": "John",
        "town": "NY",
        "date": "2020-09-01"
    },
    {
        "name": "Issue",
        "qualifier": "102",
        "date": "2020-06-01"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

This answer was written before your edit. The general idea still applies. This answer also assumes that you have valid JSON (your example is not valid as written).

But first, don't use `JSONParser` or `JSONGenerator` unless you absolutely need to. They're very verbose, and it's easy to mess something up. There are a few, very specific cases where using those classes is warranted, but instead of those, you should be using `JSON.serialize()` and either `JSON.deserialize()` or `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`.

If none of the JSON attribute names are problematic for Salesforce (i.e. they don't start with an underscore, a number, or use a reserved keyword), then you can create a series of Apex classes to mimic the structure of your JSON, and deserialize using that.

```java
public class MyJSON{
    public List<MyDate> dates;

    public class MyDate{
        public String name;
        public String qualifier;
        // The "date" attribute name may cause some trouble
        public System.Date date;
    }
}

MyJSON result = (MyJSON)JSON.deserialize(givenJSONString, MyJSON.class);
system.debug(result?.dates.size());
```

Alternatively, you can deserialize untyped (typically into a `Map<String, Object>`). Working with a `Map<String, Object>` or a `List<Object>` tends to involve a lot of explicit typecasting.

```java
Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(givenJSONString);

List<Object> dates = (List<Object>)result.get('dates');

system.debug(dates?.size());
```

The `?.` is the Safe Navigation Operator. It allows us to skip some null checks. If you really want to see if "dates" exists in your JSON though, you could check `result.dates == null` in the first example, or `result.containsKey('dates')` in the second example.

Comment: okay, but what if I have to use JSONParser as it is required by API I am calling.

Comment: Also, I got the following error: 
System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to List<ANY>